# Bizarre Alpha Animation Issue on a View inside a FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a component that looks something like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
  // The following two are added programmatically during construction
  <View> // match-parent in both dimensions, act as an overlay
  <RelativeLayout> // Bar across the top of the component, e.g. notification bar type thing

  // User's content goes here

</FrameLayout>
```

The idea is that user will place the custom `FrameLayout` somewhere and populate it with content, and when it's constructed, it will programmatically add a `View` with zero alpha that covers the entire layout and then a short and wide bar across the top used for alerts/notifications. When the alert bar is touched to expand, the overlay's alpha is animated to around 50% to gray out the area that cannot be touched. Like how a `DialogFragment` will gray out the rest of the screen when shown.

Originally the overlay is simple like: (omitting some keywords for brevity)

```
<View alpha="0.0"/>
```

And that gets inflated.

In the `FrameLayout`'s class, I create a couple animations:

```
AlphaAnimation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 0.5f);
AlphaAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 0.0f);
...
// in some initialization code I put in a couple of extra details
fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
fadeInAnimation.setDuration(500);
fadeOutAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(500);
```

And when the touch action occurs, I simply call them like `overlay.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation)`.

The strange behavior is that if the overlay is initialized to some small alpha, the animation doesn't do anything. I can verify that it at least gets called, but the alpha stays the same.

However, if I leave the overlay's alpha at its default 1.0, and set its visibility to `INVISIBLE` at constructio, the animations will correctly trigger. This also works if the starting alpha is something like 0.6. The fadeInAnimation snaps to 0 alpha and brings it up to 0.5, and then the rest acts normally.

I haven't yet tested to see if there's some lower bound on where the alpha breaks, or if there is some kind of relationship between the range on the animation and which values are invalid.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386953/alphaanimation-does-not-work

Comment: @StoneBird Looks like I didn't search properly. That seems unintuitive. If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll give you the bounty credit.

Comment: see posted. And added a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quoted in the linked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386953/alphaanimation-does-not-work):

> The problem is in android:alpha="0". This property sets transparency
>   of a View
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha
>
> When alpha property is equal to 0 then animation is changing
>   transparency from 0*0.0f=0 to 0*1.0f=0. When alpha property is set to
>   1 then animation is changing transparency from 1*0.0f=0 to 1*1.0f=1.
>   That's why in first case you can't see text and in the second
>   everything works as expected.

Meanwhile I also suggest you to try out `Animator` or `ObjectAnimator` objects, which are simple xml files typically stored in your `animator` folder. It support several attributes and I think it animates the properties in an intuitive way. That is, if you want it to animate from 0 to 1 it will change the property directly from 0 to 1.

Example code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will award when the timer is up.